# Vendor id and product id from device path

Tags: java, windows, usb, native-code

I need to get a vendor id and device id from a known device path (like "D:\").
I need to do it in java but I could do it in c native code and call the function in java.
I've tried some java libraries such as javax.usb however I can't associate a device with it's path. 
Now I have finished all my ideas. Can someone help me or give me a way to do it?
I need it for windows/macOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927475/windows-how-to-enumerate-all-connected-usb-devices-device-path). You'll probably need to use JNA or JNI to interface with the native Windows `SetupDi` functions to parse through and find device paths that you care about.

Comment: Could i used this in java or is it better to write a script in c++?

Comment: You should be able to call native APIs with JNA/JNI, but you could also use a script. The better one depends on what you are truly trying to accomplish here.