# how to get vendor id of USB based barcode reader in Android

Tags: android

i have **bar-code scanner** that is connected to the android phone through mini USB. for that i need to get **vendor id and product id** of cordless

Comment: cordless? what's that?

Comment: cordless = got no cable-based connection

Comment: Take a look in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927475/windows-how-to-enumerate-all-connected-usb-devices-device-path

Comment: mini USB == cordless???

Comment: simple i need to get vendor and product id of that device