# How to see which device is installed and uninstalled

Tags: windows, usb

When I am using my laptop (i.e. writing on keyboard)c, some device is being installed and uninstalled constantly (I hear the windows sound of it). I cannot use windows when it's undergoing (lag). How can I find which usb port/device is installed and uninstalled?

I know this is a programming portal, but i don't have account on serverfault, and maybe anybody here just knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[windows - How to enumerate all connected USB devices' device path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927475/windows-how-to-enumerate-all-connected-usb-devices-device-path):

**"**
MSDN says that there's a generic USB device interface class named `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE` with the `GUID` {A5DCBF10-6530-11D2-901F-00C04FB951ED}:

The system-supplied USB hub driver registers instances of 
`GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE` to notify the system and applications of the presence of USB devices that are attached to a USB hub.

http://www.velleman.eu/images/tmp/usbfind.c contains a code example that seems to do what you want to do, using the DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE GUID.

**"**