# How to target a specific USB hub port?

Tags: c++, windows, usb

I have a program that will periodically try to talk to ~40 devices connected via multiple USB hubs. To my knowledge, there is no way to differentiate these devices based on data stored in the unit. The devices attached will constantly be changing over time as well. What I was wondering is how to target a specific usb hub's port. So for example, I have a device connected in hub 2 port 4 and a device connected to hub 4 port 1. I want the software to scan each and every port on each and every hub so that I can catch that these two ports have something attached while none of the others do. Is there a way to target and check every port statically? More so maybe I'm just asking if there's a way I can see USB addresses on a windows PC and talk to that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [windows - How to enumerate all connected USB devices' device path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927475/windows-how-to-enumerate-all-connected-usb-devices-device-path)